# jQuery UI Todo List not working, need some guidance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am woking with jQuery UI and I made an attempt to create a "to do list" app. I have it functioning up to a point, but the task won't display correctly in the sort div I have attempted to create. It's supposed to display as a "bar" with a delete button and a completed option. But it currently displays as text. Am I supposed to incorporate jQuery directly inline in the html as well?

Here is my fiddle of the app in it's current state:

[Todo List App FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/VisionsIC/L0469ar6/2/)

I will display only the jQuery portion of the coding. The complete version is on the Fiddle.

```
$("document").ready(function() {

$('#due_date').datepicker();
$('#add_task').button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus" } }).click(function() { 
$('#new_task').dialog('open'); }); // end click
$('#new_task').dialog({ width: 350, 
                       height: 300, 
                        modal: true, 
                     autoOpen: false, 
                        close: function() { 
$('#new_task input').val(' '); /*clear fields*/
                }, buttons: { 
    "Add Task" : function() {
            var task_name = $('#task').val(); 
            var due_date = $('#due_date').val();
            var begin_li = '<li><span class="done">%</span><span    class="delete">x</span>';
            var task_li = '<span class="task">' + task_name + '</span>'; 
            var date_li = '<span class="due_date">' + due_date + '</span>'; 
            var end_li = '</li>'; 
$('#task_list').prepend(begin_li + task_li + date_li + end_li); 
$('#task_list').hide().slideDown(250).find('li:first') 
               .animate({ 'background-color':'rgb(255,255,204)' },250) 
               .animate({ 'background-color':'white'},750)
               .animate; 
// end animate 
$(this).dialog('close'); 
}, "Cancel" : function() { 
$(this).dialog('close');
    } 
  } 
}); 
// end dialog
//Marking as complete
$('#task_list').on('click', '.done', function() {
    var task_item = $(this).parent('li');
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.detach();
            $('#completed_list').prepend($this);
            $this.slideDown();
    });
});
//Sortable
$('.sortlist').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortlist', 
         cursor: 'pointer', 
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight', 
         cancel: '.delete,.done' 
}); 
//Delete
$('.sortlist').on('click','.delete', function() { 
  task_item.effect('puff', function() {
    $(this).remove(); 
    }); 
  });
```

Help and guidance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "bar", do you mean progress bar?  Could you add some screenshots to your post to clarify?

Comment: a task bar with the task title and a green completed button floated to the left and a delete button floated to the right

Answer (score 0):

One problem is with your click event. You are only moving the `.done` span element to the completed list. Try this:

```
$('#task_list').on('click', '.done', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var task_item = $this.parent('li');
    $this.detach();
    $('#completed_list').prepend(task_item);
    task_item.slideDown();
});
```

In this case, the `span.done` is still being removed, but the whole `li` element is moved to the lower list.

There is also a problem in your CSS, corrected code below:

```
#task_list li, #completed_list li {
    border: 1px solid rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding-top: .1em;
    line-height: 170%;
    margin-top: .2em;
}
```

The original code had an extra curly brace after `rgba`, which presumably had a knock on effect on subsequent code.

**EDIT** 
The delete function is also a little faulty. Here's the corrected code:

```
$('.sortlist').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var task_item = $(this).parent('li');
    task_item.effect('puff', function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

(basically, `task_item` wasn't defined).

Regarding the title, the problem is that `id` attributes must be unique, but in your HTML, 2 elements have `id="task"`. If you change your input tag to something like:

```
<input type="text" name="task_title" id="task_title">
```

...and your jQuery code to:

```
var task_name = $('#task_title').val();
```

...the title should appear.

Comment: thank you Michael, it's almost there. it now adds the task to the sort list but, you can't see the title of the task, and the delete function still won't work.

Comment: @AaronWilson: See updated answer above, hope that helps!

Comment: it works! But, how come the Task Name isn't displaying?

Comment: is that something to be addressed in the css?

Comment: @AaronWilson: No, if you inspect element you can see that the task name is empty. This is because 2 elements have the same id in your HTML. See updated answer.

Comment: @AaronWilson: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped solve your problem :-)